# make a new variable from existing data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I need some help with forming a new variable in a dataframe
I have a very large dataset were i want to make a new variable from existing data in another column.
Here is an example.

```
>>> df
   A  B   
0  a  1  
1  b  2  
2  c  3  
3  a  5  
4  d  6
```

I wwant to create a new column with the values a and c in A and name them ac, and the b and d and name them bd
Final result should look like. Kind of grouping them from A and give the group a new name in a new column.

```
>>> df
   A  B   C
0  a  1  ac
1  b  2  bd
2  c  3  ac
3  a  5  ac
4  d  6  bd
```

/Jonas

Comment: how are the mappings in C determined?

Comment: a or c should result in ac in C column...that is a and c should be set as beloning to a group called ac..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [4]: mapper = dict(a = 'ac', b = 'bd', c = 'ac', d = 'bd')

In [5]: df['C'] = [ mapper[x] for x in df['A'] ]

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   A  B   C
0  a  1  ac
1  b  2  bd
2  c  3  ac
3  a  5  ac
4  d  6  bd
```